# AWS Lambda (Python) response 403

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When try to do a

```
r_payload = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
print(r_payload)
```

on lambda i get this responde:

```
<Response [403]>
```

i dont know what to do, could someone try to tell me what im doing wrong?

```
print(r_payload.text)
Access denied | url used Cloudflare to restrict access
```

When i use the get on postman, works fine...

Comment: what is the `url` ? It looks like authentication is required.

Comment: what is r_payload.text returning ?

Comment: @balderman the url is https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&world=Antica on my PyCharm works perfect...

Comment: @Haha <title>Access denied | www.tibia.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>

Comment: According to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61089665/access-denied-url-used-cloudflare-to-restrict-access-get-request-postman adding the following header MIGHT help you : header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'} 
It is not an accepted answer but you can always try

Comment: @Haha i try it and same issue