# GET request to opensea API giving 403 error

Tags: api, rest, get, http-status-code-403, opensea

I'm trying to retrieve the asset info from a specific collection using the asset endpoint.

Example:

https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset/0x1a92f7381b9f03921564a437210bb9396471050c/2000/?format=json

Now, if you open that on your browser, it works flawlessly, but on your app or postman it just gives a 403 error by CloudFlare.
This is not a 401 error and we shouldn't need an API key for this.

So what is going on and how do I fix this? Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61123103/17490003

Comment: The same problem here. I am trying to use the headless chrome, still not working.